# How do I overlay these buttons on top of an image for a background in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Currently, I'm attempting to create a simple main menu for a game using Tkinter as a simple GUI since it's a simple RPG game and Python however the image overlays the buttons in all circumstances.

I've tried using some other solutions like placing them or creating a window but I can't find a straight answer of how to make that either.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
(PIL is from when I was using a JPG before.)   

root = Tk()
content = ttk.Frame(root)
root.geometry("600x600")

background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bred.png"))
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=580, height=600)

content.grid(column=0, row=0)

Btn1 = Button(content, text="Play", width=5, height=1)
Btn2 = Button(content, text="Kill me", width=7, height=1, command = 
root.quit)

backgroundlabel = tkinter.Label(root, image=background)
backgroundlabel.image = background

backgroundlabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Btn1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(130))
Btn1.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
Btn1.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

Btn2.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=(130))
Btn2.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
Btn2.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you expect your image to be? Underneath the buttons?

Comment: I'm trying to put the image under the buttons yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your background's master is set to `root` while your buttons are set to a frame. The first thing you need to do is set both to the same master, i.e. changing background master to `content`:

```
backgroundlabel = tk.Label(content, image=background)
```

Next you need to deal with the stacking order. You can call `widget.lift()` to raise the buttons to top:

```
Btn1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(130))
...
Btn1.lift()

Btn2.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=(130))
...
Btn2.lift()
```

Comment: Sorry to add a new question but it only now shows part of my image. https://i.imgur.com/jqqQLk6.png - Any idea why?
If I move it around it doesn't show any more of the image, no idea how to show the full image.